# how do i split string in c#?

Tags: c#

In my application I need to stored given following data's..

**Street, City, State, Postal and Country**

---

**---Sample Address ---**

***Street: #306, Los Angel,opp Line Tower,3rd cross

City/Town: Ang Mo Kio

State: Al-mera

Postal : 520506

Country: Dubai

---

But my string like means

**"#306, Los Angel,opp Line Tower,3rd cross\nAng Mo Kio Al-mera 520506\nDubai"**

from above string how can i split for Street, City, State, Postal and Country.

**[Note: all fields are not mandatory field, even might be empty. So When empty field pass value as empty string for corresponding field]**

C# variable declaration: string street,city,state,postal,country=string.empty;

How can i store value from above orginal string split into correspondng c# variables?

Comment: use the split(); function of the string, it returns an array with the string parts.

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var address = "#306, Los Angel,opp Line Tower,3rd cross\nAng Mo Kio Al-mera 520506\nDubai".Split(new [] {',', '\n' })
var array = address.Split(new [] {',', '\n' })
```

Then iterate through an array to assign the variables. That will split by new lines and commas and empty fields will be kept (i.e. multiple commas are not an issue)

Answer (score 0):

Use C# [Split()](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split) function

```
string[] add_var=addrString.Split(',');
```

Comment: Look at his input, this will not work, his address line has multiple commas.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var address = "#306, Los Angel,opp Line Tower,3rd cross\nAng Mo Kio Al-mera 520506\nDubai".Split(new[] { ',', '\n' });
        var array = Page.Request["Address"].ToString().Split(new[] { ',', '\n' });


        if (array.Count() != 0)
        {
            if (array[array.Count() - 1].ToString() != "") // Country
                sCountry = array[array.Count() - 1].ToString();
            else
                sCountry = "";


            var sTemp = array[array.Count() - 2].ToString().Split(new[] { ' ' });

            if (sTemp.Count() != 0)
            {

                // PostalCode
                if (sTemp[sTemp.Count() - 1].ToString() != "")
                {
                    sPostalCode = sTemp[sTemp.Count() - 1].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    sPostalCode = "";
                }

                //State Name
                if (sTemp[sTemp.Count() - 2].ToString() != "")
                {
                    sState = sTemp[sTemp.Count() - 2].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    sState = "";
                }

            }
            else
            {
                sPostalCode = "";
                sState = "";
            }

            if (array[array.Count() - 3].ToString() != "") // City
                sCity = array[array.Count() - 3].ToString();
            else
                sCity = "";


            for (int i = 0; i < (array.Count() - 3); i++)  // Street
            {
                sStreet = sStreet + array[i].ToString();
            }

        }
```